# Unbiased estimator of a square root of chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ be a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
I need to show that $S$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$.
As from the definition, I see that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^{2}_{(n-1)}$.
My thought process follows like this:

1. If $X\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$, then by definition $X\sim Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2},2)$.
2. Apply above definition to this problem. Since I need to find if $S$ is biased or not, I must compute the expected value of S.
3. I also know that $E[Y^a]=\frac{\beta^a\Gamma(\alpha+a)}{\Gamma({\alpha})}$ when Y is a gamma distribution. I should be able to apply the same concept to this problem.

After calculations, I obtain something like this:

$E[S]=\frac{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma{(\frac{n-1}{2})}}\times\frac{\sigma}{n-1}$

How do I prove that above is an biased estimator of $\sigma$? Obviously the value of the gamma functions change as the n changes (between even and odd). Is there a more systematic way of obtaining this? I'm not quite sure how to deal with this gamma function and go on to compare $E[S]$ with $\sigma$. Is there a way for me to simplify this gamma function further?

Comment: "How do I prove that above is an biased estimator of $\sigma$? " What do you have to do to show that something is a biased estimator of something?

Comment: @Remy I guess it is similar but I have trouble simplifying those gamma functions. I'm not quite sure if there's a numerical way of showing that this gamma equalizes to something that's more simple - something that I can use to compare it with $\sigma$

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have to prove that it is not unbiased - which I can do by computing $E[S]-\sigma$. My problem is in simplifying that gamma function that I have in my $E[S]$.

Comment: $E(S)\ne \sigma$ , so $S$ is biased (or not unbiased) for $\sigma$.

Comment: Might be dumb - how do you prove that fat gamma function in front is not equal to 1?